# Polymer core-selector does not refresh

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

The Dart code for my Polymer element looks like this:

```dart
@CustomTag('my-element')
class MyElement extends PolymerElement {
  final List<String> colors = toObservable(['red', 'green', 'blue']);
  MyElement.created() : super.created();
}
```

And the HTML looks like this:

```dart
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      .core-selected {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>
    <core-selector id="selector" selected="1">
      <template repeat="{{color in colors}}">
        <div value="{{color}}">{{color}}</div>
      </template>
    </core-selector>
    <hr>
    <!-- Prints the selected index, but does not update -->
    <div>{{$['selector'].selected]}}</div> 
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="my_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Using `<div>{{$['selector'].selected]}}</div>` correctly shows the index of the selected `color`, but picking a different color does not refresh the value of `selected`. Am I using this correctly? Or is this a bug?

Comment: I would expect this to work. `selected` is a published property and should therefore be observable. Maybe a problem of the Dart wrapper.

Comment: Günter, I believe you are correct. I've filed a bug: https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/issues/115.

Comment: you have a typo: {{$['selector'].selected]}} should be {{$['selector'].selected}}

Answer (score 1):

I agree it's a bug, but in the meantime you can work around it like this

```
<core-selector id="selector" selected="{{selected}}">
...
<div>{{selected}}</div>
```

with the backing code containing the obvious

```
@observable int selected = 1;
```

I do wonder if your version works when used in a pure JS environment? But that's another question.